# Why member-of-pointer at operator() doesn't work?

Tags: c++

Why work the function call operator not together with a member-of-pointer operator?

```
struct F
{
    void operator()(){}
};

int main()
{
    F * f = new F;
    f->();   // Why this doesn't compile?
}
```

Comment: For future questions, please include compiler error message for [mcve].

Comment: Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Tm-7FR) applicable to any of the answers you've got.

Comment: I did know how to circumvent this issue. My question is more, *why* it's not allowed. I thought, there would be a technical reason for or such.

Comment: Then @Alan's explanation is what you are asking for. `f->` roughly becomes `(*f).` and expects to be followed by a member (variable or function).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the C++ gods simply thought the syntax was too obscure. The correct syntax is either:

```
f->operator()();
```

Or:

```
(*f)()
```

If the `->` operator isn't overloaded then `f->` is roughly equivalent to `(*f).`, `(*f).()` doesn't compile either, you would have to use:

```
(*f).operator()();
```

Answer (score 5):

You should call it as  `f->operator()()` or `(*f)()`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any specific reason.

Both `->` and `.` expect the name of a member to follow, and you haven't provided one.

There's just no need to create a special case in the grammar to permit that. It's complicated enough as it is!

`(*f)()` is the way to go.

Sorry if that's brief and unfulfilling, but if you're looking for some deep meaning here I think you're bound to be disappointed!